# How do you pass data from Objective C to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How do you pass a data object from an Objective C file to a Swift file ?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"details"]){
    //create the swift file and set the property I want to pass here


    }

}
```

In the swift view:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


public class SwiftViewController: UIViewController{

    var passedObject:NPSCustomObject!

    public override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried bridging the header?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I know how to add header files to the bridge file so I can access them the swift file, is that where I pass the object through from objc -> swift ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the "details" segue is set up in the storyboard as passing to a view controller of type `SwiftViewController` (which it should be for the workflow you've hinted at), you don't create an instance of the latter — the segue has already done that for you. You can access it inside `prepareForSegue` as [`segue.destinationViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController).

Assuming your project is already [set up with the proper headers for bridging Swift to (Obj)C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), you just need to cast `segue.destinationViewController` to the type you're working with so you can access its members. For example:

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"details"]){
    SwiftViewController *vc = (SwiftViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.passedObject = // put your instance of NPSCustomObject here
}
```

Comment: Not the bridging header. That's used by Swift code to interface with Objective-C code. This is the other way around, where his Objective-C code needs to `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`, the system generated header for his Swift objects.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to use NotificationCenter:

**Objective C to Swift**

Objective C

```
NSDictionary *myData = @{@"data1" : @"value1", @"data2": @"value2"};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:myData];
```

Swift

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "myNotificationName"), object:nil, queue:nil, using:yourFunction)

func yourFunction(notification:Notification) -> Void {
 if let extractInfo = notification.userInfo {
             print(" my data: \(extractInfo["data1"])");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a naive way saving data with NSUserDefaults :

Objective-C Class :

```
NSString *myObjcData = @"from Objective-C";

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:myObjcData forKey:@"data"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Swift Class :

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Receive data ---> with NSUserdefaults
    let mySwiftData: AnyObject? = prefs.valueForKey("data")
    println("data is \(mySwiftData)")

}
```

It's not very elegant but I guarantee it works!
Hope it helps.

Comment: a bit late, but don't you also need a Notification to indicate that the change was made?

Comment: This would of course always work but is definitely terrible.